# How to show a button based on div color sequence jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sass

I'm trying to set up an "Easter egg" type page on a website where someone can click on colored squares to cycle through a range of colors. There are 8 squares and I want to make a button appear if all of the squares are in the correct color sequence using jQuery. I have the following setup that works for the color cycling, but am new-ish to jQuery and not sure how to check for the correct color sequence. I'm working in Rails 5.

```js
    var backgrounds = ["red", "green", "yellow", "orange", "purple", "violet",
                       "pink", "steelblue", "blue"]; 

    function setColor(el) { 
        el.colorIdx = el.colorIdx || 0; 
        el.style.backgroundColor = backgrounds[el.colorIdx++ % backgrounds.length]; 
    }

var buttonMessage = "Success";
function buttonCheck() {
    if ($('#div1').css('background-color')=='rgb(255, 255, 255') {
        buttonMessage;
    } else {
        buttonMessage = "Failure";
    }
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = buttonMessage;
}
```

```css
div .colored {
        background: blue;
        height: 100px;
        width: 100px;
        margin: 10px;
        float: center;
    }
```

```html
<div class="row">

    <div class="colored" id="div1" onclick="setColor(this)"></div>
    <div class="colored" id="div2" onclick="setColor(this)"></div>
    <div class="colored" id="div3" onclick="setColor(this)"></div>
    <div class="colored" id="div4" onclick="setColor(this)"></div>

    </div>

    <div clas="row">

    <div class="colored" id="div5" onclick="setColor(this)"></div>
    <div class="colored" id="div6" onclick="setColor(this)"></div>
    <div class="colored" id="div7" onclick="setColor(this)"></div>
    <div class="colored" id="div8" onclick="setColor(this)"></div>

    </div>
<button onclick="buttonCheck()">Click here</button>
<h1 id="test"></h1>
```

Edit: Instead of making a button appear I thought it would be easier to click a button and print a success response if the color combination is correct. The above code reflects my changes but I still can't get it to work.

Comment: One of the solutions, you can loop through them using `nth-child()` this [link](https://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/) will help you

Comment: I am still not understanding if you want a button to be appear only when all squares are with same color. Is this right ?

Comment: I want a button to appear when each square is a specific color, but not all squares are the same color. Ex: Sq1: blue, Sq2: red, Sq3: blue, Sq4: yellow, etc...

Comment: How the colors are setted? Randomly, on click? The color sequence is the order of the `backgrounds` array?

Comment: The colors all start as blue and are cycled on click